# Ajax form submission in cakephp 

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have used ajax form submission in cakephp

`echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array('url'=> array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'add_comment'), 'update' => 'feedback_'.$value['contest_submission']['id']));`

After i submitting the form the update div content become null.How i can retain the content itself and just hide the div

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set Callback function(http://book.cakephp.org/view/1361/Callback-Options) on request complete. try following code and change alert message to your function to hide div if it works.

```
echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array('url'=> array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'add_comment'), 'update' => 'feedback_'.$value['contest_submission']['id'], 'complete' => 'alert( "Hello World" )'));
```

Please update here if it will work or not!